# How can I build Node.js using static libssl and crypto libraries?

Tags: openssl, node.js, javascript

**[Update] A solution has been found: https://github.com/robhawkes/node-extension/issues/1**

I'm embedding Node within a browser extension and don't want the user to manually install openssl or even know what it is, I'd rather it was bundled into the Node build or statically linked to files held within the browser extension.

I already know how to disable openssl completely in Node and that solution works, however I'd like to have openssl enabled incase my users require it at some point.

I'm also aware of the `--openssl-includes` and `--openssl-libpath` `./configure` flags, however they didn't seem to do what I wanted when I pointed them to a directory containing a static build of libssl and crypto – the build failed because it couldn't find the "SSL_library_init" function.

Any ideas how I can do this? If it help, I'm happy with a solution just for OS X for now. I can work out the rest later.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: It's worth noting the export/import restrictions on SSL/cryptography software. If you bundle OpenSSL with your software you may run into legal issues http://www.blackducksoftware.com/media/_wp/SEEC-Guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks Sam, I'll make sure to look into that once I've found out if this is even possible.

Answer (score 4):

A solution has been found via. Ryan Dahl, creator of Node. Basically I just needed to use the new gyp build process that seems to have arrived with the 0.6 versions of Node. Within the `options.gypi` file that is generated during build you can set the `node_use_system_openssl` to `false` and it will use a static library for openssl.

More details: https://github.com/robhawkes/node-extension/issues/1